# connect 3 tables with cascade SQL(phpmyadmin)

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, cascade

I have 3 tables, first table is "user" that contain all users.
second table is "teacher" that contain just teachers, and the last table is "student" that contain just students.
Now I want to connect all this table together and when I add new user with role teacher its should added just to teacher table, and when I add new user with role student it should be added just to student table.

user table:
https://prnt.sc/fioCEiBtc2dr   without relations

teacher table:
https://prnt.sc/zrJcHeSQKsUg  with relation https://prnt.sc/04iyp6MzDFoa

student table:
https://prnt.sc/yYnYIX7eFuI1  with relation https://prnt.sc/MQTtyfiDAUq1

For now if I add new user with teacher role or student role it adding this user just to teacher table. What should I do?

Comment: That's NOT how `cascade` works. Cascade deals with updating, deleting, or setting null depending upon the FK relation, there is no automatic insert to other tables.

Comment: Check out triggers, that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that is the answer
all want need to do it just add triggers to user table.

BEGIN
IF NEW.role = 'teacher' THEN
INSERT INTO `teacher` (`id_user`) VALUES (NEW.id_user);
END IF;
END

and same trigger for student table